# Analogue GitHub for XCode

Tags: xcode, git

I'm new at iOS developing.
I want to develope for iOS with my friend, but GitHub provides private project for money. 
Does anyone know analogue of GitHub, which provides free private project and supports XCode 4.2?

Comment: git doesn't care about your language or data -- hence it does support xcode. You could always set up a remote on a server of yours

Comment: Is your question, "how to run something like GitHub for private repositories"? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390828/how-can-i-have-github-on-my-own-server/8390894)

Comment: Is your question, "How to share code with your friend"?  As mentioned you could set up a repo that is accessible to both of you.  Alternatively, since git is distributed, you technically don't even need a central repo.  You could just add remotes for each other's machines, and pull/push from each other's repos as needed.

Comment: thx to all for reply. BitBucket is pretty usefull to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/). Sadly, no more details are available since the site has been down for the past several hours (which I suppose isn't a glowing advertisement for the service).

Answer (score 0):

You can just setup a private server of your own, easily.  You can use git for source control and [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) for issue tracking, for instance.

Or as others have mentioned, [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) should work when the service is working again.