# Software version of GitHub Network

Tags: git, github

GitHub's network is great but is slow and sometimes not really reliable because not updated fast enough.

Is there any software version of it? Seems the official client does not have it. And the command-line is not as beautiful & usable.

Comment: I highly doubt that a GUI is more usable than the git command line but I suppose it's a personal preference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I have Github on my own server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390828/how-can-i-have-github-on-my-own-server)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the Github interface, though very pretty, is not open.

If you want to host Git including a web-based interface I'd recommend using Gitweb in combination with Gitolite. See a demo of Gitweb here: http://git.kernel.org/