# Generate Web Pages For Git Repository?

Tags: git, web-services, github, server, html

I believe a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390828/how-can-i-have-github-on-my-own-server) question to this has been asked before but its not quite the same. I would like to host a private git on a server, and generate web pages based on it with all the nice statistics and stuff similar to github (does github have an api another for this [other than the one I am about to mention]?). I have looked into [gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) but I only see installation instructions for Ubuntu and centos. The computer I would likely be running this server on has some constraints and I would like to go with arch if I can. There are other applications on the server and I would like to be able to just run a script and generate the page, and maybe modify it with some CSS or something (possibly something nice like github, but nothing too too heavy duty)?

Thanks!

~ TFB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for something lighter-weight than GitLab, you might want to look at [Gitweb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb), which is an official part of the Git project. It might even already be installed on your server. Gitweb is [well-supported on Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gitweb).

Another possibility is [Go Git Service](http://gogs.io/) (GOGS), which is a relative newcomer written in Go. GOGS is designed to be lightweight and [easy to set up](http://gogs.io/docs/installation/). It looks like there [are AUR packages for Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gogs).